# Logging in to a Admin - Member website with PHP and MySQL - Log in not working

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, logout

I am building a database driven website using PHP and MySQL. The login form was working perfectly, but after I added a new function to my code to make the user login to either admin or member pages, the login stopped displaying the (for example) "Welcome, Pat, Administrator" or "Welcome, Gina, Member" on the form.

The form is a small one that shows up on each page of the website, either as a login or as a reminder that they're already logged in (using sessions). Now, when I log in a person, it does take them to the admin or member pages, but it doesn't display the login information in the form and the logout button won't work when clicked. Here is my code for the login and the logout, as well as code for the functions I'm using to get to the admin pages or member pages.

THE LOGOUT FORM, which should show them as logged in until they click the logout, but it isn't working:

```
<form method="post" id="logoutform.inc.html">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Logout</legend>  
        <?php

        include('includes/functions.php');

        if(isset($results)){
            if ((isset($_SESSION['loginName'])) === $result['email'] && (isset($_SESSION['password'])) === $result['password']){
                echo "Welcome, <br />";
                echo "$level, <br />";
                echo get_name($results); 
                // print_r($_POST);
                print '<br />';
            } else {
                 var_dump($results);
            }
        }

        ?>
        <br /><br /><br />     
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="logout" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

THE LOGIN FORM:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" id="loginform.inc.html">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        <label for="loginName" class="loginName">Username:</label>
        <input id="loginName" name="loginName" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($loginName['loginName'])); ?>" />
        <label for="password" class="loginName">Password:</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo (isset($password['password'])); ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
    </fieldset>
 </form>
```

THE LOGOUT FUNCTION:

```
function logout() {
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: home.php');
};
```

THE LOGIN FUNCTION That takes you to either admin or member pages: THIS ONE ISN'T printing anything in the else eiher:

```
function login($loginName, $password) {
    $results = connect($loginName);
    if ((isset($_SESSION['loginName'])) === $result['email'] && (isset($_SESSION['password'])) === $result['password']){
        var_dump($loginName);
        print "Welcome, $loginName";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry. You are not in our database";
    }

    if ( 'a' == $results['level'] ){
        $level = "Administrator";
    } elseif ( 'm' == $results['level'] ){
        $level = "Member";
    } else $level = '?';

    if ($level === "Administrator"){
        header('Location: /tires/admin/home.php');
        exit();
    } elseif ($level === "Member"){
        header('Location: /tires/member/home.php');
        exit();
    }
    include('includes/logoutform.inc.html');
}
```

HERE IS THE CONNECT query:

```
function connect($loginName){
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT email, level, password FROM members WHERE email    = '$loginName'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $results = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;
};
```

Comment: Can you show me any result of the  connect($loginName);

Comment: It says it's NULL but I'm not sure why because it was working perfectly before I added the : if ($level === "Administrator"){
         header('Location: /tires/admin/home.php');
        exit();
    }elseif ($level === "Member"){
        header('Location: /tires/member/home.php');
        exit();
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in **function login($loginName, $password)** kindly refer the code below, I check the code it shows that **logoutform.inc.html** was not included.

```
function login($loginName, $password) {
$results = connect($loginName);
if ((isset($_SESSION['loginName'])) === $result['email'] && (isset($_SESSION    ['password'])) === $result['password']) 
{var_dump($loginName);
print "Welcome, $loginName";}

 else {

     echo "Sorry. You are not in our database";
  }
include('includes/logoutform.inc.html');

 if ( 'a' == $results['level'] )  {
     header('Location: /tires/admin/home.php');
 } 
 elseif ( 'm' == $results['level'] ) {
     header('Location: /tires/member/home.php');
 }
 else $level = '?'; 

 }
```

Comment: I wish this would have worked for me. It is still refusing to logout - and when it logs in, it doesn't show the correct login information: Like Welcome, Pat, Administrator. It was, once, working perfectly, until I made it go to the different folders - the admin and member folders. That is when it broke. Thank you so much for helping and God bless you. If you have anymore ideas, I will definitely look forward to them.